# Whether to make a new variable to be returned in a Python function

Tags: python, function, naming

Looking for some guidance on whether to assign a new variable in a function before returning the result, as follows:

```
# create function to take in a number
# which is then taken to the power of another number
# make a new variable called result, and return that variable

def exponential(number, power):
    result = number**power
    return result
```

Or whether I can simply return the calculation all in one line:

```
def exponential(number, power):
    return number**power
```

I'm extremely new to programming, so I'm aware that there's likely mistakes everywhere.
Any feedback on how I asked this question, anything else in the code, or any keywords that would have helped me find this in Google are also welcome.

Comment: Did you try both versions? Did you obtain a different output?

Comment: Yes, appears no difference. If I enter an integer for `number` they both return integers. And entering a decimal for `number` results in both functions returning floats.

Comment: they are pretty much the same, the only reason you will want to put your result in a variable is to use it for more things or to clarify what it is

Comment: The question is more about conventions than anything. I'm not stuck with it, just want to try and learn good practices early on.

Comment: The result is the same, obviously, but the second version (the one without the `result` variable) will run faster since there is no need to instantiate a new variable. If you need to run that function thousands of time in a loop, the second version is the way to go.

Comment: @alec_djinn that is exactly the reason I asked this. Computational efficiency is (embarrassingly) not even something that cross my mind. Thanks!

Comment: Worrying about efficiency in a trivial case like this is known as "premature optimization". Write code which makes sense to you; *then* if it's really too slow, think about ways to make it faster. See also https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/80084/is-premature-optimization-really-the-root-of-all-evil

Comment: @tripleee that makes total sense. So if I were in a job in the same scenario, generally speaking I should just make it readable (version 1), as it's less likely to cause bugs, and any efficiency gain is negligible. Correct?

Comment: This is a generalization from the observation that many developers needlessly focus on performance when they should just get the job done and move on. If you don't know your personal antipatterns yet, it's probably reasonable that you should heed the same advice. Once you develop a personal style and individual habits, this principle may become less pertinent. A  bad overall design is hard to fix with a simple rule of thumb, and yet often is the ultimate cause of any serious performance issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no compelling reason to prefer one over the other.

For nontrivial computations, assigning the value to a variable might make the code more readable as well as easier to debug (because you can `print(...)` or - better yet - `logging.info(...)` the value and otherwise examine and manipulate it before `return`ing it) but where exactly to draw the line is entirely up to you and the intended audience.

If it's completely your own code and you are completely familiar with the logic in this function, you probably don't need a variable. If this is shared code where future maintainers might not be familiar with the functionality, or where bugs have frequently required fixing in the past, correspondingly adjust in the opposite direction.

Comment: Writing good code really is an art isn't it. 
Lots to consider, and this is about as trivial as it gets!

Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0):

You can return the result in one line as in your second example.